# Cambiar fondo de parrafos con onmouseover

Tags: javascript

Quiero que al pasar el raton por un parrafo par todos los parrafos pares tengan el fondo blanco y los impares tengan el fondo gris, lo mismo al contrario, si pasas el raton sobre un parrafo impar, todos los parrafos impares tendrán fondo blanco y los parrafos pares el fondo gris

```js
let parrafo = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for (let i = 0; i < parrafo.length; i++) {
  parrafo[i].onmouseover = function () {
    for (let j = 0; j < parrafo.length; j++) {
      if (j % 2 == 0) {
        parrafo[j].style.backgroundColor = "white";
      } else {
        parrafo[j].style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      }
    }
  };
  parrafo[i].onmouseout = function () {
    for (let j = 0; j < parrafo.length; j++) {
      parrafo[j].style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui fugiat
      suscipit nam quos iure inventore totam animi quam non sapiente, a sed
      alias, voluptatibus ab ex hic placeat cupiditate maxime facere? Facilis
      dolorum blanditiis maxime veritatis eius aut maiores, natus velit numquam
      obcaecati est incidunt aperiam animi aliquid, consequatur placeat!
</p>
<p>
      Molestias reiciendis tempora, quod molestiae deserunt totam sit officiis
      omnis dignissimos ut repellendus, neque in culpa, cum temporibus illo eius
      ab natus illum quisquam. Vero numquam totam molestiae quasi, sit non
      consequatur consequuntur maxime excepturi a, doloribus repellendus sed?
      Quam id dolorum delectus neque aspernatur debitis similique consequuntur,
      ut culpa?
</p>
<p>
      Cupiditate quis possimus provident quas velit mollitia tempora aspernatur
      assumenda quibusdam recusandae, suscipit aliquam voluptates ullam nemo
      sint dolorem beatae eligendi! Ratione eaque minima temporibus est, quos
      molestias, ducimus, dolorum odit quo voluptas officia blanditiis assumenda
      hic. Praesentium, animi. Iste ipsum ea cum inventore tempore. Veniam
      cumque eligendi molestiae error?
</p>
<p>
      Necessitatibus sed aperiam ea tempore optio doloribus natus voluptatibus
      sit dolorum blanditiis alias rem nihil vero explicabo placeat nulla amet
      provident, ut soluta accusantium? Sapiente laudantium hic nam error,
      delectus iste illo asperiores nisi voluptatibus adipisci reprehenderit
      ipsum repellendus, laborum quia ad quisquam! Quis porro ducimus,
      perspiciatis amet ea sit.
</p>
<p>
      Assumenda, quia. Ex assumenda eos eligendi eaque accusamus, explicabo nisi
      fugiat neque eveniet! Accusamus obcaecati animi blanditiis at aspernatur
      corporis quisquam eaque? Quasi quas recusandae deleniti expedita
      molestiae. Qui id laudantium sapiente placeat labore quia, quae at fuga,
      molestiae animi perferendis consequatur eum assumenda veritatis minus,
      quaerat odit. Voluptatem, at.
</p>
```

El problema que tiene mi código es que al pasar el ratón, ya sea un párrafo par o impar siempre se colorea de blanco los párrafos impares y de gris los pares

Comment: Poner un trozo de código está bien... pero ya que por encima es un problema de desarrollo web y puedes poner un [mre] embebido en la propia pregunta, lo suyo sería que lo hicieses... O por lo menos indicarnos cual es el problema con el código que has puesto.

Comment: Ya he corregido la pregunta, espero puedas quitarme la valoración negativa que me has puesto, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias maneras de hacer lo que buscas, la más sencilla para mi es esta: (te dejo comentarios en el código con explicaciones)

```js
let parrafo = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for (let i = 0; i < parrafo.length; i++) {
  parrafo[i].onmouseover = function () {
    // Primero comprobamos si es par o impar para saber si empezamos en el índice 0 ó 1
    const startIndex = i % 2 === 0 ? 0:1;
    // A continuación simplemente iteramos sobre los párrafos sumando +2 a la j en vez de 1
    // de esa manera no hace falta hacer comprobaciones pues sabemos que saltaremos el que no toque
    for (let j = startIndex; j < parrafo.length; j += 2) {
    // Tampoco hace falta el else puesto que el color de fondo ya es blanco normalmente
      parrafo[j].style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
    }
  };
  parrafo[i].onmouseout = function () {
    for (let j = 0; j < parrafo.length; j++) {
      parrafo[j].style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui fugiat
      suscipit nam quos iure inventore totam animi quam non sapiente, a sed
      alias, voluptatibus ab ex hic placeat cupiditate maxime facere? Facilis
      dolorum blanditiis maxime veritatis eius aut maiores, natus velit numquam
      obcaecati est incidunt aperiam animi aliquid, consequatur placeat!
</p>
<p>
      Molestias reiciendis tempora, quod molestiae deserunt totam sit officiis
      omnis dignissimos ut repellendus, neque in culpa, cum temporibus illo eius
      ab natus illum quisquam. Vero numquam totam molestiae quasi, sit non
      consequatur consequuntur maxime excepturi a, doloribus repellendus sed?
      Quam id dolorum delectus neque aspernatur debitis similique consequuntur,
      ut culpa?
</p>
<p>
      Cupiditate quis possimus provident quas velit mollitia tempora aspernatur
      assumenda quibusdam recusandae, suscipit aliquam voluptates ullam nemo
      sint dolorem beatae eligendi! Ratione eaque minima temporibus est, quos
      molestias, ducimus, dolorum odit quo voluptas officia blanditiis assumenda
      hic. Praesentium, animi. Iste ipsum ea cum inventore tempore. Veniam
      cumque eligendi molestiae error?
</p>
<p>
      Necessitatibus sed aperiam ea tempore optio doloribus natus voluptatibus
      sit dolorum blanditiis alias rem nihil vero explicabo placeat nulla amet
      provident, ut soluta accusantium? Sapiente laudantium hic nam error,
      delectus iste illo asperiores nisi voluptatibus adipisci reprehenderit
      ipsum repellendus, laborum quia ad quisquam! Quis porro ducimus,
      perspiciatis amet ea sit.
</p>
<p>
      Assumenda, quia. Ex assumenda eos eligendi eaque accusamus, explicabo nisi
      fugiat neque eveniet! Accusamus obcaecati animi blanditiis at aspernatur
      corporis quisquam eaque? Quasi quas recusandae deleniti expedita
      molestiae. Qui id laudantium sapiente placeat labore quia, quae at fuga,
      molestiae animi perferendis consequatur eum assumenda veritatis minus,
      quaerat odit. Voluptatem, at.
</p>
```

Por cierto, esto funciona gracias a las [`closure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), razón por la cual dentro de cada función `onmouseover` tenemos un único valor de `i` disponible, que es exactamente el valor que corresponde al elemento que ha disparado la función. Es decir, para cada elemento javascript está *"creando una función diferente"*.

Comment: Gracias, no se me habia ocurrido lo del operador ternario para saber si es par o impar, de todas formas como es que funciona ese operador ternario? js no necesita poner parentesis en la condicion para funcionar??